# Expressjs middleware static typed path and path with param conflict

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm about to implement REST endpoints for authenticated users and non-authenticated users in expressjs. My current understanding of REST has led me to following design pattern:

**User resource**

Token user:

```
/users/self GET, PATCH
```

Non-token user:

```
/users POST

/users/:user_id GET
```

**Profile image resource**

Token user:

```
/users/self/profile-images POST

/users/self/profile-images/:profile_image_id PUT, DELETE
```

Non-token user:

```
/users/:user_id/profile-images GET
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to use this pattern without having `:user_id` parameter become `self`, i.e `{user_id: 'self'}`. I would want them to act as two isolated path types without interference, one strict and one dynamic. Is this possible? If so, how?

A code example of my current implementation looks like following:

```
// instPrivateUserRestRoutes.js (token-user)
router.use('/users/self', [
  instAccountRestRoutes(restControllers),
  instAuthenticationSessionRestRoutes(restControllers),
  instPrivateProfileImageRestRoutes(restControllers)
])

// instPublicUserRestRoutes.js (non-token user)
router.use('/users/:user_id', [
  instPublicProfileImageRestRoutes(restControllers)
])

// instRestApp.js (mount point for top resources)
router.use(instPrivateUserRestRoutes(restControllers))
router.use(instPublicUserRestRoutes(restControllers))
```

Comment: Its not exactly clear where your problem is. The routes registered at `router.use('/users/:user_id'` should not be called if the if one of the routes in `router.use('/users/self',` handles the request. So in which case is `instPublicProfileImageRestRoutes` called if the uri starts with `/users/self`?

Comment: @t.niese `/users/:user_id/profile-images GET` seems to get called when i make a request to `/users/self/profile-images GET`, which isn't a registered method on the target route. I therefor expected a 404 Not Found response. My intent is to have these two path types isolated from each other. My concern originates from the fact that this doesn't seem to be the case. I've either missed something in the code, or i've misunderstood expressjs middleware composition.

Comment: Is `user_id`  numeric or can it be anything except `self`, because if `user_id`  can only be a numeric value then there would be another solution ?

Comment: @t.niese In this case `user_id` is intended to be a numeric value. Though i believe a more generic solution that supports multiple value types would be beneficial. As `user_id` could be replaced with other identifiers such as `username` or `email` or something of sort in other route paths.

Comment: I updated the answer to also contain a solution the requires `user_id`  to be a numeric value.

Comment: @t.niese After doing some more research i found this thread discussing the issue: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2760

It seems like this use case reaches beyond the capabilities of ExpressJs, which leaves us with alternative solutions. The alternative solutions we've currently discussed are: `1. differentiated paths` `2. RegEx in path` `3. early response/error middleware`

Should we settle on this? If so, i'll accept your answer once updated with an explanation/note covering these points.

Comment: this ends somehow more and more in an opinion based discussion. There is no right or wrong with any of these 3 approaches. I update my answer to include a conditional middleware that is probably closest to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do it to create a conditional routing middleware. The factory dunction takes as first argument a callback method that determines which router should be use, and as second argument a list of routers, and returns a new middle war that conditionally uses one of the routes.

```
function conditionalRouting(cond, routes) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    try{
      // get the index for the router that should be used
      var idx = cond(req, res)

      // call this router and pass req, res and next to it
      routes[idx](req, res, next)
    } catch(err) {
      // in the case an error occurs in on of the steps "throw" that error
      next(err)
    }
  } 
}
```

You could then use it that way:

```
app.use(
    '/users/:user_id',
    conditionalRouting(
      (req, _) => req.params.user_id === 'self' ? 0:1,
      [routerForSelf, routerForUser]
    ))
```

An other way would be to handle this case explicitly with a middle ware that triggers a not found error:

```
function forceNotFound(req, res, next) {
    var error = new Error('resource not found')
    error.status = 404
    next(error)
}
```

And add this as your last middleware

```
router.use('/users/self', [
  instAccountRestRoutes(restControllers),
  instAuthenticationSessionRestRoutes(restControllers),
  instPrivateProfileImageRestRoutes(restControllers),
  forceNotFound
])
```

This way it is clear that express should stop at that point.

This will look different to what the standard `Cannot GET /the/path` would look like, but you normally don't want to display those default error messages anyway.

If you want to have the same kind of message then you could write:

```
var parseUrl = require('parseurl')
var encodeUrl = require('encodeurl')

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    var msg = 'Cannot ' + req.method + ' ' + encodeUrl(parseUrl.original(req).pathname)
    var error = new Error(msg)
    error.status = 404
    next(error)
})
```

If you only want to handled numeric ids you could use this:

```
router.use('/users/:user_id(\\d+)', [
  instPublicProfileImageRestRoutes(restControllers)
])
```

That way `instPublicProfileImageRestRoutes`  would only be called if `user_id` is numberic.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. Would you say this approach is preferred over using a different uri structure to isolate the two path types? Do you know if there's any documentation regarding this issue? I would assume this to be a quite common problem to encounter when building more complex REST api's.

Comment: @Sakki Well you could argue that they could have added a `res.stopRouting()` similar to the `stopPropagation` you have with events.  The way it is currently implemented you could have `router.use('/user', requiresAdditionalAuthenication, criticalTasks); router.use('/user', notCiriticalTasks)` how would you do that if express would stop if none of the routes in `criticalTasks` match?